# I just can't seem to get my german umlauts right with Powershell V2

Tags: powershell, encoding, powershell-2.0, diacritics

Hello there and thanks in advance for your help.

I have a script which transforms my output into a desired format. I load the file with

```
$PreSystem = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Users\Soc.20150119.txt")
```

I process it and do this:

```
 # Write to file
  $output | Out-File -Filepath C:\Users\Soc.20150119_output.txt -append
```

Now each time, the Umlauts ä, ö, ü, ß are displayed as question marks in my output.

I tried

```
-encoding ASCII
-encoding unicode
```

and so on. But the problem persists. Can someone help me out, I'm starting to pull my hair :) Thank you so much!

BR,
Tobi

Comment: Have you checked if the error is in the import instead of export? Probably powershell is not reading the file in the correct way. Try with `get-content "C:\Users\Soc.20150119.txt" -Encoding Default` (if not working try also with another `-Encoding`, like `Unicode`)

Comment: i tried -encoding unicode and ASCII on both in and output. Haven tried default yet though. Didn't help to date.

Comment: Does it work with 
[IO.File]::ReadAllText?

Comment: When I try to do it with get-content instead i get this error:
`Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'split'.
At line:23 char:24
+ $all = $PreSystem.split <<<< ("`n") 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (split:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound`

Comment: Are you using powershell v3+? Add `-Raw` to the cmdlet parameter `get-content "C:\Users\Soc.20150119.txt" -Raw -Encoding Default`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue using ReadAllText, you can specify the encoding like this:

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Users\Soc.20150119.txt", [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode)
```

You can also test with `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`, which I believe should work too.